# When creating an animation to cause a UIImageView to go up and down (almost float) infinitely, how do I stop a pause at the end of the animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Here's the code I'm using to take a `UIImageView` and make it float up and down.

```
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            self.slider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -5.0);
        }];
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.25 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            self.slider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 5.0);
        }];
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.75 relativeDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            self.slider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0.0);
        }];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

However, it comes out looking like this with this delay after the animation ends and before it restarts.

How do I make it fluid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what effect you're going for exactly, but I think this gives you something like your code does without the delay. I usually do this by animating a constraint, rather than using transforms. In this example, I've made an IBOutlet (topCon) to the constraint to the top of the view:

```
-(IBAction)floatView:(id)sender {
    static int i= 1;
    static float duration = .25;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        self.topCon.constant = self.topCon.constant - (5 * i);
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        i = (i == 1 || i == 2)? -2 : 2;
        duration = 0.5;
        [self floatView:self];
    }];
}
```

Comment: That was exactly the effect I was going for. Floating up and down infinitely.